# What is this red button?

Tags: pokemon-go

[image]

Just received this image. Is that a IV calculator? Or a fake gps tool?

Comment: Why the down votes for a seemingly reasonable question?

Comment: @Jerry Because GPS spoofing is frowned upon, and the user "received" this image seems a little fishy.

Comment: I agree that GPS spoofing is unfair, but to me, this question is about identification, not for instructions on how to use it.  Please do not misunderstand me; I am relatively new to this Stack Exchange community and trying to understand the general feeling.

Answer (score 7):

This is the icon of Samsung's Game Tools. It is an option of all recent Samsung Android devices. Pressing it gives you a range of usefull tools like screen capture and switching apps. This has nothing to do with cheating or spoofing. You see this when pressing out:

[image]